# Monitor Does Not Change mode to 75Hz Which it supports :(

Tags: display, fps

I bought a Samsung monitor. (S22R350)
I connected it to my Windows PC. This monitor is said to be supporting 75Hz. And My graphics card can support this frame rate too. (AMD Radeon 7700HD)

But when I get to monitor settings I can't change the mode from 60Hz to 75Hz. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you installed the AMD drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[S*R35* User Manual](https://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=US&CttFileID=7591644&CDCttType=UM&ModelType=C&ModelName=LS22R350FHNXZA&VPath=UM/202002/20200206124251320/Web_Manual.zip)
has this specification on page 41:

[image]

If your connection is not via HDMI, 75Hz will not be available.

Even if the connection is HDMI, you will find in the manual pages
41-43 more restrictions on the frequency as regarding the technology used.

Given that there are strict restrictions on when 75Hz can be used,
your setup must not be one where this is possible.
In any case, the manual recommends 60Hz, perhaps for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar Samsung monitor (model number: LS24R35A). Physically, it looks identical as the model you're describing. I was having similar issues because I was only able to get 72hz refresh rate at best.

According to the manual, you have to turn off Free Sync in order to get the full 75hz in vertical frequency. So I turned it off and It worked. The option is in the monitor's option menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).